# How to Xml Reader child nodes with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("https://betting.api.bwin.com/V2/CalendarFeed.svc/?x-bwin-accessId=apikey");
    string tablo = "";
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {           
        if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) )
        {                
            if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
            {
                tablo += "<table>";
                tablo += "<caption>" + xmlReader.GetAttribute("name")
                +  "</caption>";                 
            }               
        }          
    }

    tablo += "</tr>";
    tablo += "</table>";
    div.InnerHtml += tablo;   
}
```

Comment: What does the xml look like?

Comment: <CalendarFeed>
<Sport id="5" name="Tennis">
<League id="16969" groupId="7544" name="Challenger ATP - Helsinki (FIN) - Hardcourt" regionName="World">
<Event id="4060685" groupId="560054" name="Jurgen Zopp (EST) - Victor Hanescu (ROU)" date="2014-11-14T12:30:00Z" live="true" cutOffDate="2014-11-14T17:30:00Z"/>
<Event id="4060684" groupId="560053" mainBookId="4060318" mainGamesNbr="4" name="Henri Laaksonen (SUI) - Egor Gerasimov (BLR)" date="2014-11-14T15:00:00Z" live="false" cutOffDate="2014-11-14T20:00:00Z"/>
</League>

Comment: @BahaAdıyaman You should post that in the question, not in a comment so it can be properly formatted and easier to read.

Comment: example xml code in this link https://betting.api.bwin.com/V2/CalendarFeed.svc/?x-bwin-accessId=MDVhZDk4MjgtYzQzZC00ZjU3LTlkNzktMGI1ZjgzNjNjNDYx

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? It definitely gets the `name` attribute of every element from all child nodes.

Comment: Using your code, I was able to load the linked XML into a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, with the following result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdlez.png.  What problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML does not seem to be well formed.

Check out how to create a proper one [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp) and about reading childnodes check [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm)